# why the forgot password link doesn't redirect to my app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-b2c

I've set up my asp.net mvc app according to this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L101) and if you see that line in startup.auth.cs, it says that when the user clicks on "Forgot Password" link, it should redirect to my app at which point it should catch that error in the line 101 that I've linked to and then redirect the user to the proper reset password flow.

However, when clicking forgot password, the flow is never directed back to my app, but rather I see this screen:

[image]

Where can I check as to why this happens? Is this supposed to be in my sign in policy or is there some setting in application or tenant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens if you enable development mode in your custom policy.
Either remove the lines, or set it to DeploymentMode:Production.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights